# Can I create random forest with RandomForestClassifier which will consist the same trees?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-trees

Based on answers to [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/16800/82) question, I should be able to build a random forest with all the same trees by using `bootstrap = False, max_features = None, random_state = 42` parameters.

I wrote [quick code to test it](https://gist.github.com/QuantumDamage/29474994f4dc51cd170ea706b0ad646f), and it seems that different trees are created.

Is it possible to create a random forest using `RandomForestClassifier` which will produce the same trees?

Comment: Why do you want them all to be the same?

Comment: it's [right there in the accepted answer to the linked question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/16804/23305) if you read the entire answer

Comment: @kbrose - as an example step in process of creating decision tree, looking for its hyperparameters, creating homogenous forest (with those hyperparameters), adding bootstrap, adding fraction of features and increasing n_estimators. So such forest would be something different than single tree, but with exactly the same predictive capability.

Comment: @oW_ Yes, I read the entire answer, especially **You can fix this by passing the same seed to each DecisionTreeClassifier which you can do using random_state=something. RandomForestClassifier also has a random_state parameter which it passes along each DecisionTreeClassifier.** - I did that, and it did produced trees with fixed seed but different for each one. So it seems that there is no such possibility?

Comment: this homogenous forest would *not* be different from a single decision tree. If they all share the same random seed then the randomness introduced by bootstrap and max_features would disappear ... that's exactly the point... that's also the reason why you can't do it with RandomForestClassifier..unless I'm missing something here

Comment: Agreed oW_. If all trees are exactly the same you don’t have a forest, you have a tree. If the trees are not exactly the same then your forest has more predictive capabilities than a single tree. Maybe I’m not understanding something crucial here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a random forest where all decision trees are the same. (I am trusting you are trying to do this as an educational exercise, not as something serious. :))

You tried to do this by setting `random_state` and cited my answer from

- [Why `max_features=n_features` does not make the Random Forest independent of number of trees?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16800/why-max-features-n-features-does-not-make-the-random-forest-independent-of-num)

Indeed, as you discovered, my answer is not fully correct.

I have edited it to add

> While this removes the stochasticity component of the training, the decision trees would still be different. The thing is that sklearn ensembles generate a new random seed for each child based on the random state they are given. They do not pass along the same `random_state`.
>
> You can see this is the case by checking the `_set_random_states` method from the ensemble base module, in particular [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/ensemble/base.py#L549), which propagates the `random_state` across the ensembles' children.

As you can see, sklearn uses the `random_state` you give RandomForest to create new random states for each child,

```
for key in sorted(estimator.get_params(deep=True)):
    if key == 'random_state' or key.endswith('__random_state'):
        to_set[key] = random_state.randint(MAX_RAND_SEED)
```

Therefore they will be different. This is done presumably because heterogeneity is what makes an ensemble powerful. Notice this is not specific to RandomForest, but to any sklearn ensemble.

Sorry for my incorrect answer to the question you cite. If you want, you can use the random forest implementation. That one is completely homogeneous.

Comment: Thanks very much for correction and additional information. Thats the information I was looking for!